# Optimization of cake pan volume from area of pan

Tags: derivatives, optimization

It was difficult to accurately word this question, so hopefully a bit of context will clear that up.

**Context:**

I have a cake dish that is made by cutting out squares from the corners of a 25cm by 40 cm rectangle of tin.

```
                          40cm

                 _____________________
                |_|                 |_|
       25cm     |                     |
                |                     |
                |_                   _|
                | |_________________|_|
```

A 3D cake tin is made by folding the edges once the squares have been cut away.

What size squares must be cut out to produce a cake dish of maximum volume?

**My working:**

1. I know that the area of the pan without the squares will be:

   (40 - 2X) * (25-2Y) = Volume
2. But that's about all I can wrap my head around. I know that the pieces cut off are sqaures, so they will have the same width and length. But that's all I can think of doing...

*How exactly can I find what size square will produce a maximum volume for the container?*

I'm pretty terrible at math, and I know it looks like I've done nothing to try and solve this. But I honestly am at a bit of a loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Suppose we remove $x\times x$ squares. The "finished" pan will have length $40-2x$, width $25-2x$, and depth $x$. So its volume $V(x)$ is given by 
$$V(x)=(40-2x)(25-2x)(x).$$
You want to choose $x$ that maximizes $V(x)$. Note that we will need $0\lt x$ and $2x\lt 25$.

Comment: So by differentiating V(x) as V`(x), and then equating it to zero, I can solve for the maximum(s). (And check where X is a maximum using a sign graph) ?

Comment: Yes, that will do it. "Expand" the expression for $V(x)$ given above, differentiate, set the derivative equal to $0$, and check you really have a maximum. The checking can be done as you described, or else you can see that $x$ near $0$ or $12.5$ is bad, and there is only one critical point between $0$ and $12.5$.

Comment: Thank you. I believe I have solved the problem. My answer is within your parameters of 0, and 12.5.

Your answer has been chosen as the solution.

Comment: You are welcome. I get $x=5$ but my arithmetic is unreliable.